# Notification doesn't show up when activity is closed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to make a notification that shows up when a certain day of the year happens.  I can't seem to figure out how to get Android. How can I get android to check up every day on this app?

```
cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    dayOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    payDays = new int[12];

    payDays[0] = 60;
    payDays[1] = 88;
    payDays[2] = 123;
    payDays[3] = 151;...

    // Checks when to send the notification
    if (dayOfYear == payDays[0] || 
        dayOfYear == payDays[1] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[2] ||
        dayOfYear == payDays[3] ||

    {

        Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Phone Commission")
        .setContentText("Expand for totals")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify2);


        Notification notification = new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder)
                .bigText("Add-a-Line: " + AALNote +
                         "\nUpgrades: " + UPGNote +
                         "\nNew Lines: " + NLNote +
                         "\nYour total commission is: " + "$" + totalNote).build();

            NotificationManager notify = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
              notify.notify(0, notification);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an Alarm.  You can't do something like this in an Activity.  You should set that alarm in a service, because doing so in an Activity will make it become lost once the Activity is finished.

Comment: API to this is AlarmManager?

Comment: Yes.  It basically allows you to set a PendingIntent that will be called when time is elapsed.  You can either have it use the hyper-accurate versions or the less accurate ones.  For your case I'd use the less accurate ones, a few seconds won't matter.  Note that this will not work around reboots, to do that you'll have to make a broadcast receiver listen to BOOT_COMPLETE and launch your service.